# Could you add a fav system on answers?

Tags: feature-request

There are great answers on this websites which is no secret but no system to fav them. If you find this useless just ignore me ^^

Comment: The little star below the vote counter is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Starring question captures a lot of changes to the thread, including new answers. Not sure if it captures answer edits.

Comment: I'm speaking about answers not threads. Straight to the point.